# Android adjustResize with fixed margins

Tags: android, keyboard, margin, window-soft-input-mode

I am facing an annoying problem for a few hours.

I have a relative layout with a logo which has a marginTop and a button aligned to the bottom, which has a marginBottom. Between these two views there are also some other views, centered.

[image]

The problem occurs when the keyboard is opened. What I want to happen is lift everything up. What does happen is that the button is lifted, the logo stays in a fixed position, and the other views are squeezed in the middle (on small devices they even disappear).

[image]

I know the problem can be solved if all the other views would be relative to one another, starting from the logo or button (never both!). But in this case, the logo and the button won't be in the desired places.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: try putting it in a scrollview

Comment: Put other stuff views in RelativeLayout. It may resolve your problem

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren I already put it in a scrollview

Comment: @Moses the other stuff is in a separate layout. Other than that, the code is very similar to what Koen Van Looveren suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you discribe here:

do not forget the FILLVIEWPORT = true. for the scrollview

This is what I figured out and it works perfect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="be.vanlooverenkoen.testing.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, but the edittext is squeezed. In my case, since I have                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp" for logo and   android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" for button the size of the edit text is even smaller (sometimes even gone).